# compiling and running java8/jdk8 code in netbeans - Uncompilable source code

Tags: java, netbeans-7, java-8

After playing with preview of [JDK 1.8](http://jdk8.java.net/lambda/) in notepad and compiling files from command line, I thought I would try with netbeans and see what happens.

I have successfully added JDK 1.8 and changed the following settings:

> properties -> libraries -> java platform: **JDK 1.8**
>
> properties -> sources -> Source/Binary format: **JDK 8**

When I `Clean and build` the project from netbeans, it builds successfully. And suggests to execute project with following command:

> javac 1.8.0-ea
>
> To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
>
> **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0/bin/java -jar "C:\Java8\JavaBacon\dist\JavaBacon.jar"**

and it runs just fine from command line!

But when I try to `Run` the project, I get following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: <any>
```

It can build, but can't run??

My current workaround for this, is just to put the Java8 code in separate `Java Class Library` and call it from main project, since it can build the library.
Obviously when using java8 features, you get red squiggles, lack of intellisense and autoformatting changes `->` to `- >`, but it builds! ( very nice :D )

But what is the reason for not being able to `Run` the project?

### UPDATE:

The exception goes away when disabling `Compile On Save` setting under:

> Properties > Build > Compiling

http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=199293

Comment: can you please add an answer you find out as stackoverflow's answer and mark it accepted? So your question in search will look complete.

Comment: Your JDK is java8, but what about jre? May be your trying to run with jre of older version.

Answer (score 1):

The exception goes away when disabling `Compile On Save` setting under:

> Properties > Build > Compiling

Reference: [netbeans bug database](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=199293)